# Can't change background of ActionBar Sherlock

Tags: android, background, styles, actionbarsherlock

I have `ActionBar Sherlock`with `ViewPagerIndicator`like [here](http://www.limecreativelabs.com/actionbarsherlock-y-viewpagerindicator-la-pareja-perfecta/).

I'm trying to change `ActionBar`background but it does nothing.

Here is my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        //...
        android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators" >
```

**styles_mystyle.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme.Mystyle" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_mystyle</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Mystyle</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Mystyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Mystyle</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Mystyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Mystyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Mystyle</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_mystyle</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_mystyle</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Mystyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Mystyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_actionbar</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/background_actionbar</item>
    </style>

    //more styles

    <style name="StyledIndicators" parent="@style/Theme.Mystyle">
        //some items for ViewPagerIndicator
    </style>

<resources>
```

**background_actionbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#DD84A4E8"
        android:startColor="#7784A4E8" />

</shape>
```

Do you know where the problem is?

Comment: I think `<item name="background">#FF0000</item>` should be `<item name="background">@drawable/background_actionbar</item>`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to change it here (I was trying other possibilities). I have `<item name="background">@drawable/background_actionbar</item>`

Comment: do you have several values folders (like values, values-v11, values-v14, ...) ?

Comment: Yes, I have values, values-v14